# Checking if Session has Timed Out

Tags: asp.net, session, timeout

This is my base class for all pages except EndSession.aspx

```
override protected void OnInit(EventArgs e)  {  
base.OnInit(e);  

if (Context.Session != null)  
     {  
         //check the IsNewSession value, this will tell us if the session has been reset.  
         //IsNewSession will also let us know if the users session has timed out  
         if (Session.IsNewSession)  
         {  
            //now we know it's a new session, so we check to see if a cookie is present  
             string cookie = Request.Headers["Cookie"];  
             //now we determine if there is a cookie does it contains what we're looking for 
             if ((null != cookie) && (cookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0) )//&& !Request.QueryString["timeout"].ToString().Equals("yes"))  
             {  
                 //since it's a new session but a ASP.Net cookie exist we know  
                 //the session has expired so we need to redirect them  

                 Response.Redirect("EndSession.aspx?timeout=yes");  
             }  
         }  
     }  
 }
```

But on EndSession I try to navigate back to, say default.aspx, and then this code above just redirects be back to EndSession.aspx.

So for better clarification:
Step 1: Go to mypage.aspx
Step 2: Wait for timeout
Step 3: try to navigate away
Step 4: get redirected to EndSession.aspx
Step 5: try to navigate away
Step 6: GoTo set 4

Setp 6 should be actually being able to navigate away...

(if needed pelase ask for further clarification)

Any ideas?

THANKS!!!

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve that you can't do with, let's say FormsAuthentication? I mean what is your reason for redirecting to default.aspx, what magic should happen there?

Comment: I'm open to other ideas. Although I should mention that I'm not worried about triying to Authenticate the user. There are other things stored in the Session State and if they are unexpectidly removed could cause a problem. I'm open to better alternitives, but I still think what I am trying to do should be achievable.. no?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got rid of the basepage that I had originally.

Put this in the Session_Start of Global.asax

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    string cookie = Request.Headers["Cookie"];
    // Code that runs when a new session is started
    if ((null != cookie) && (cookie.IndexOf("ASP.NET_SessionId") >= 0))//&& !Request.QueryString["timeout"].ToString().Equals("yes"))  
    {
        if(Request.QueryString["timeout"] == null || !Request.QueryString["timeout"].ToString().Equals("yes"))
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?timeout=yes");
    }
}
```

Put this on the Defualt.aspx page:

```
 if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        if (Request.QueryString["timeout"] != null && Request.QueryString["timeout"].ToString().Equals("yes"))
        {
            Response.Write("<script>" +
               "alert('Your Session has Timedout due to Inactivity');" +
               "location.href='Default.aspx';" +
               "</script>");
        }
    }
```

This solution works even when the timeout occurs on the Default.aspx page

The discusion for the solution I used is posted here: [How to stop basepage from recursivly detecting session timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3423184/how-to-stop-basepage-from-recursivly-detecting-session-timeout)